# how can I find the location of the solution/project on my harddrive in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio

I want to know where the solution/project is stored on my hard drive.

I would have thought right clicking on the project from within Visual Studio would have the information on where it is stored on my hard drive, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Click on the project itself in the solution explorer and in the properties window it lists the project folder.

Only works if you've actually saved the project though. I.e. newly created projects don't have a location.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to select the project in the solution explorer and then click File / Save As or press F4 and view the 'Project Folder' property.

Answer (score 0):

Start up Visual Studio and go to Tools->Options.

In the dialog box that opens, make sure to check the box that displays "Show All Settings."

From there, you should find a setting called "Projects and Solutions" which will have the list of default locations for projects, templates, etc.

Answer (score 0):

When you have loaded you project in Visual Studio select the solution in the Solution explorer window and then select Properties window. You will see "Path" in the Properties window which points to the actual file.

Answer (score 0):

Open one of the files in your Solution and hover over the tab in the code window. The full path will show up in a tooltip.

You can also go to **Window | Windows...** which shows you full path to all open files.